# Http/2 preloaded css is not applied and considered unused

Tags: html, css, http2

I'm trying to get a simple http/2 server push demo to work with the following simple hello world example:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Http 2 push demo</title>
    <link rel="preload" href="core.css" as="style">
</head>
<body>
 Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

core.css

```
body {
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
```

In Chrome 66.0.x the css seems to be loaded successfully but I keep getting the following warning:

> The resource http://localhost:8080/core.css was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

and the css is not applied to the html body.

Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Comment: Right now you are _only_ pre-loading the resource, but you are not _using_ it in any way afterwards. You still need a “normal” `<link rel="styesheet" href="core.css">` to actually embed this styesheet into the document and get it applied.

Comment: Indeed! I expected the preload link to actually replace the stylesheet reference. Now it works. Thanks @CBroe

Comment: Correct which is why preload is pointless for CSS. It’s more intended for resources which are not obvious (e.g. a font referenced by a style sheet that wouldn’t otherwise be seen until the style sheet was downloaded). See here for more info: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/02/preload-what-is-it-good-for/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you are *only* pre-loading the resource, but you are not *using* it in any way afterwards.

You still need a “normal” `<link rel="styesheet" href="core.css">` to actually embed this stylesheet into the document and get it applied.